# When is the ground state potential energy equal to the kinetic energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm reading "Introduction to Many Body Physics" by Piers Coleman, and in a simple harmonic oscillator example he makes the statement that "the zero-point kinetic and potential energies are equal".

I know I've seen this kind of thing before but I'm having a hard time probing google and my brain. Is this generally true for the ground state of a quantum system? i.e. if $H=p^2/2m+V(x)$ is it true that $<p^2/2m>=<V(x)>$ in the ground state?

Comment: For a $1/r$ potential, the expectation value of the potential energy is -2 times the EV of the kinetic energy. They have neither the same magnitude nor the same sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a consequence of the quantum version of the [virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem#In_quantum_mechanics),
in the case of SHO, the equality $<p^2/2m>=<V(x)>$ holds in every stationary state.

Comment: Probably a pandemic lapsus :-) I'll correct it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, it is generally not true - you can see this by adding any constant $V_0$ to the potential, which obviously shifts $\langle V \rangle$ but not $\langle p^2/2m\rangle$.

It *is* true in the specific case of the quantum harmonic oscillator, where $V(x) = \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2$.  The reason for this ultimately lies in the symmetry between $x$ and $p$ (the Hamiltonian is, up to some factors, $H=p^2+x^2$) which is the origin of many of the (classical and quantum) harmonic oscillator's important and unique properties.